# angular - circular dependency

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

For the first time ever I am facing this issue and I am struggling a lot in trying to figure out why and how to fix it.

I have two services, service1 and service 2, but apparently, there's a circular dependency like this:

```
serv1 <- serv2 <- serv1
```

The services code is the following:

```
angular.module('service1', [])
.service 'serv1', ['$rootScope','$http','$location','serv2',
  function ($rootScope, $http, $location,  serv2){
    serv2.doMyOtherThing(...)
   }
]
```

and service2 is the following:

```
angular.module('service2', [])
.service 'serv2', ['$rootScope','$http','$location','serv1',
  function ($rootScope, $http, $location,  serv1){
    serv1.doMyThing(...)
   }
]
```

why is there a circular dependency? how do I solve this?

Each service is specific for something (serv1 variou utilities and serv2 array utilities) and I need to use the two together sometimes but it's currently not possible.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see this [Miško Hevery's blog](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) you will understand that :

```
...
.service 'serv1', ['$rootScope','$http','$location','serv2'

.service 'serv2', ['$rootScope','$http','$location','serv1',
```

The **serv1** needs **serv2** and **serv2** needs **serv1**. And this is going to train a circular dependency.

So you could use a third service

Or you can resolve this like this :

```
angular.module('service1', [])
.service 'serv1', ['$rootScope','$http','$location','serv2',
    function ($rootScope, $http, $location,  serv2){
        serv2.doMyOtherThing(...)
    }
]

angular.module('service2', [])
.service 'serv2', ['$rootScope','$http','$location','$injector',
    function ($rootScope, $http, $location,  $injector){
        var serv1 = $injector.get('serv1');
        serv1.doMyThing(...)
    }
]
```

Comment: I hope this will help

Comment: I just updated the answer, before i maded a little mistake :p

Answer (score 1):

Use a third service, use that third service in the other ones.

example:

```
angular.module('service1',[])
.service 'serv1' [..,'servCommon', function(..,servCommon){}]

angular.module('service2',[])
.service 'serv2' [..,'servCommon', function(..,servCommon){}]

angular.module('serviceCommon',[])
.service 'servCommon' [.., function(..){}]
```

Add some common function in that `servCommon` and use them from other two.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why this circula dependecy issue happen in the first place? I don't wanna duplicate my functions  in even another service, this doesn't seem like the good thing to do here to be honest..

Comment: angular DI tries to inject `serv1` to `serv2`, but while it `serv2` is already needed to inject `serv1`, please read more about DI and circular dependency [Link to Tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/how-to-fix-circular-dependencies) 

If you dont want this workaround then you must need to change your code design in such way that no circular dependency should occur.